# Why does Uranium-235 not just fission right away and release 2 neutrons instead of 3?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I have holes in my current understanding of fission. I have two questions that I think are related to this missing knowledge.

U-235 is fissile and will fission when absorbing a neutron. My understanding is, that this split is instant. It will (most likely) split into two smaller daughter nuclei, with a combined smaller binding energy than before the split. It will also release 3 neutrons.

- Why doesn't U-235 just split right away into two smaller daughter nuclei and only release 2 neutrons?

The splitting must be near instant, otherwise you could not use this to make an a-bomb. But if I look at U-236, it has a very long half-life.

- Is it wrong to look at the processes as temporarily existing as U-236, during a neutron capture? :

  U-235 + n --> U-236 --> Ba + Kr + 3n

Comment: First note: the number of neutrons released per fission event is an average across many possible fission products, and is also split between prompt and delayed neutrons. Second, while the cross section is smaller, one does see the 235U(n,g)236U reaction. Third, U235 does have a spontaneous fission decay path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why doesn't U-235 just split right away into two smaller daughter nuclei and only release 2 neutrons?*
It does but only $0.000000007\%$ of the time does spontaneous fission occur with alpha decay being the dominant mode.

*U-235 is fissile and will fission when absorbing a neutron.*
It has to capture a neutron and it is much better at absorbing slow (thermal energy) neutrons than fast (high energy) neutrons which are produced as a result of a fission.
Thus in a reactor the fast neutrons are slowed down by a moderator which does the slowing down of the neutrons by collision and the moderator must also have the property that it is not very good at absorbing neutrons.
Once a neutron is absorbed fission becomes the dominant U-236 decay mode $(\approx 82\%)$ whilst $18\%$ of the time a gamma (energy) is emitted and U-236 is produced.
The U-236 produced as a result of a gamma decay is not much good as a fissile material as when it absorbs a neutron it is converted into U-237.
It is considered a long-lived waste product in an nuclear reactor.

*Is it wrong to look at the processes as temporarily existing as U-236, during a neutron capture?*
Not at all as explained above.

Comment: Is this intermediate state U-236m ?